# Symfony: Order form with option to login to load user details

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony

I've been working on an order form for a type of webshop. I intend to use Craue Form Bundle to split up the form over several pages. At the end of the order, the user is asked for his details (address, phone, ...). However, I also want to give the option to log in at this stage, and then load the user details from the database instead (with the option to change them if they're no longer correct).

Of course, the order process should not be disrupted if the user submits the login form.

How would I do this with Symfony3?

- I thought maybe the best idea would perform the login through AJAX
  and then fill out the form details when the response comes.
- Or I could store the already filled out order details in the session,
  but that would require submitting the entire form, not just the login
  part of it.
- But all this requires deviating from Symfony's way of doing things, which is bound to cause some trouble.

Just wondered if you have any good ideas or ready-made code out there? I seem unable to find anything that suits my needs.

Comment: What about serialize and deserialize the Data during login? Then you could reuse it.

Comment: yes, that would be one way. But perhaps the 1st solution is the cleanest and fastest for users. But I wondered if Symfony has something built in for this.